# Trying to send a struct pointer as a node to a function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have problems with parsing the parameters to the function **list_append()**. The major issue that confuses me is the the pointer inside a struct inside a struct...

Is the function asking for a data type of "LIST" and I am passing it a pointer?

When I try to compile this I get the following error:

**Please explain like I am 5.**

**Error**

```
In file included from main.c:3:0:
list.h:9:7: note: expected 'LIST' but argument is of type 'struct post *'
 void  list_append   (LIST l, int item);
       ^
```

**list.h**

```
void  list_append   (LIST l, int item);
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "list.h"

int main() {

static struct post {
    char* str;
    struct post* next;
    int item;
} head = { 0, NULL };

    struct post *p = &head;
    struct post post;

    list_append(p, post.item);

}
```

**list.c**

```
void list_append(struct node* n, int item)
{

    /* Create new node */
    struct node* new_node = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
    new_node->item = item;


    /* Find last link */
    while (n->next) {
        n = n->next;
    }

    /* Joint the new node */
    new_node->next = NULL;
    n->next = new_node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. My guess would be compiler is looking for data type LIST where as you passed in a `struct post *`. What is `LIST` anyway.? Did you define it anywhere.?

Also there is mismatch of datatype of function defined in header file and actual function definition.

Comment: Yea... No I have not defined `LIST` anywhere, only in the header file.

Comment: Look for something along the lines of "typedef xxxx LIST;" or perhaps #define LIST xxxx and post it so we can see what that type has been defined as.

Comment: Also I do not see any struct node defined. What did you mean by LIST in header.?

Comment: This is in **list.h** `typedef struct node* LIST;`

Comment: do you include list.h in list.c?

Comment: No, but I include list.h in main.c

Comment: Also I think struct node* is in compatible with struct post*. Don't you think.?

Comment: Instead of defining new structure post, you might as well use the same strucure node and pass it, assuming you have defined it in list.h

Comment: I am totally confused and lost by all those list and struct definitions everywhere. :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't define LIST anywhere, you can just change the declaration of your function in list.h to the following:

```
void  list_append   (struct node* n, int item);
```

You're implementing a linked list, so you the "list" is really just a pointer to the first node.

Otherwise, and perhaps cleaner, you could include the following in your header:

```
typedef struct node * LIST;
```

And change the declaration of your function (in the .c file) to the following:

```
void list_append(LIST n, int item)
```

Comment: I changed it now, list.h has `typedef struct node* LIST;`, and list.c has `void list_append(LIST n, int item)`. I still get the same error.